# What's happening when I do new T[1]?

Tags: c++, c++14, allocator

Quick question here:

```
template <class T>
T* allocate(std::size_t n){
    return new T[n];
}
```

So in the above code, when `n==1`, we're doing `new T[1]`, so I have two worries:

1.I heard that when allocating array, extra memory are used to store the length of the array (unsure though), so would this be malicious when having `new T[1]` a lot, wasting a lot of memory?

2.Should I free this using `delete[]` or simply `delete`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, in a typical implementation when you use `new T[n]` some extra memory will be required to store the exact length of the array, but *only for types with non-trivial destructors*.

   E.g. in a typical implementation `new int[1]` carries no memory overhead compared to `new int`, but `new std::string[1]` will carry memory overhead compared to `new std::string`.

   The extra memory is just an extra `size_t` field, meaning that percentage-wise it depends on the size of the object you allocated. If `sizeof(T)` is comparable to `sizeof(size_t)` the overhead might be considerable.

   But it all might also depend on the additional details of the implementation-specific memory allocation mechanism.

   In other words, if this a part of application-specific code it makes sense to try it and see whether it has any negative impact on your program's memory consumption. Maybe it is not a problem at all. But if you are writing a generic library, then things like that are worth paying attention to.
2. Yes, you should use `delete []`.

Comment: So a if-statement for `n==1` is recommended as a library? How would a 'decent' allocator deal with this?

Comment: @YiFei: Well, remember that if you switch between `new` and `new[]` at the point of allocation using `if (n==1)`, you will also have to switch between `delete` and `delete[]` at the point of deletion using the same `if (n==1)`. For that you will have to independently store that `n` somewhere. This has the potential to dilute (or wipe out)  all savings you achieve by doing all this, unless you allocate a lot of arrays for the same values of `n` (i.e. store just one `n` for a large number of arrays).

Comment: Exactly, now I seemed to have refreshed my concept of allocator, that another parameter is required for `deallocate`. Thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

1. RAM is cheap. It is true that if all your program does, all the time, is allocate arrays of 1 object, over and over again, then this would be slightly wasteful, true. But an occasional allocation of a 1-element array is not going to be the end of the world.
2. Use `delete[]`. If you used `new[]`, then you have to use `delete[]`. Doesn't matter how much was `new`ed. This is a fairly cut-and-try rule. No exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

1. No memory is used to store the length of the array, or at least no memory you are allowed to access. The memory manager that granted you the memory likely has  some hidden bookkeeping. Should you find this bookkeeping, leave it alone. Anything you do with it is certainly non-portable. It is also possible you will be provided memory in fixed size blocks. You will be given a block that is at least the size of `T`. Any extra memory in this block is effectively wasted.
2. Anything allocated with `new[]` must be released with `delete[]` or you you invoke undefined behaviour. Once again, do not mess with the low-level memory manager.

Comment: Isn't that said that `delete` operator would delete the first element of the array, i.e. the pointer directly pointed to, and that should be what `new T[1]` return (the whole array)? (Though never will I try...) That's related to the 'bookkeeping'?

Comment: There is no definitive answer of what will happen. The C++ standard avoids the issue, so it is perfectly acceptable for the compiler to generate code that will delete the entire universe, the one `T` exactly as you wish it, or anything in between. It would also be valid for the compiler to do absolutely nothing or print mocking insults to the console.

Comment: The standard doesn't avoid the issue, it says it's outright illegal ([new.delete.single]/12).

Comment: @ildjarn, Standard says 'requires' isn't it? It doesn't say the other way around.

Comment: @YiFei : Violating 'required' clauses means UB; and that clause says that pointers passed to non-array `delete` **must** have been allocated with non-array `new`.

Comment: @ildjarn Thank you. The Standard is scattered with "thou shalt not," but I'm still looking for confirmation of "The resulting behaviour is undefined"  or a "The compiler shall smite thine face with a decomposing trout." The best I've found is **defns.undefined** saying "Undefined behavior may be expected when... a program uses an erroneous construct or erroneous data." Which I read as "If it ain't mentioned, assume UB." right up until I finally stumble across a counter. That said, ill-formed is ill formed. Don't expect it to work whether what else will happen is defined or not.

Comment: @user4581301 : [structure.specifications]/3.1 defines 'Requires' clauses as preconditions, and [res.on.required] reads "*Violation of the preconditions specified in a function’s Requires: paragraph results in undefined behavior unless the function’s Throws: paragraph specifies throwing an exception when the precondition is violated.*"

Comment: Need to read the beginning of the doc a bit more closely. Missed that. Thanks again. @ildjarn